# Bootstrap input group not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my log in page turned into a mess. Just a few hours ago everything seemed normal but I'm not sure what I did but now its showing like this:

[image: Login page]

I am using Firefox to run.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Username</span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserId" 
CssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />

 <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-md-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Password</span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" 
CssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-lg
 col-md-2 col-xs-offset-5" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

Comment: You can try creating a live demo instead of image so that we can debug the code.

Comment: @ManojKumar I'm not really too sure how to create a live demo. Would u mind guiding me through ?

Comment: Use Bootply.com and import the code that is responsible for the output.

Comment: @ManojKumar Well, i I tried but It doesnt seem to have the problem. I am really not sure why I'm having this :/ Is there anyway i can live demo a asp.net file ?